# Thanks for making history alongside us vs. Thanks for making history with us

Tags: word-usage

> Andrew Yang (NYC mayor candidate) tweeted: Thank you to everyone who supported me and Evelyn in the campaign to help New York!  Love to you all. It was truly a people-powered campaign that broke records along the way. **Thanks for making history alongside us**. There’s a long road ahead and I am looking forward.

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/AndrewYang/status/1407703154951606273)

I don't understand why using "alongside" rather than "with":

"Thanks for making history alongside us" vs. "Thanks for making history with us"

Is there any difference in meaning between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "Thanks for making history alongside us" and  "Thanks for making history with us" have essentially the same meaning, that being "Thanks for joining us in a process that made history".

"making history with us" **could** mean "making history by using us" but that is obviously not the sense here.

One meaning of "with" is "accompanied by" as seen in [this definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/with). That is very close to "alongside".